# iproute2: How do i connect one machine to the internet via another

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, iproute2

I have the following setup:

**A** > 169.254.8.125/16 <--(ad-hoc)--> 169.254.9.109/16 < **B** > 192.168.178.21/24 <--(wifi)--> 192.168.178.1/24 < **AP/router** > internet

I want to connect A to the internet via B. So far, the routing table of A looks like this:

```
default via 169.254.6.109 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.8.125
```

The routing table of B looks like this:

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.6.109  metric 1 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.21  metric 2
```

On machine B I enabled ip forwarding doing `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and
I added a NAT rule to iptables:`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE`

I'm aware that I don't have any DNS for A, yet.

I can ping B from A and vice versa.
Shouldn't this already give A access to the internet or at least enable pinging the router? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the forward rule.

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state -–state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT